# the View cannot be rendered from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have a view which I want to change its data by changing a DropDownList.
Everything works fine but the View doesn't render with new set of data. In other word when I post data to an action method in controller it cannot return to view.
here is my code:

View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Model.Params>
    <table>
       @foreach(var item in Model)
       {
         <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
          </td>
         </tr>
       }
   </table>
    <div>
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("datetime")
              .DataTextField("DateText")
              .DataValueField("DateText")
              .Events(e => e.Change("datesChange"))
              .DataSource(ds => ds.Read("Read_Intervals", "MyController"))
              )
    </div>

<script>
    function datesChange() {
        var value = $("#datetime").val();
        $.post("@Url.Action("Kq_Read", "MyController")" + "?date=" + value);
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Kq(string date)
{
    IQueryable<Params> kq;
    if (date != null)
    {                  
        var datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        kq = db.Params.Where(p => p.LogDate == datetime);
    }
    else
    {
        var datetime = GetLatestInterval();
        kq = db.Params.Where(p => p.LogDate == datetime);
    }
    return View("Kq", kq);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Kq_Read(string date)
{
    var datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
    var kq = db.Params.Where(p => p.LogDate == datetime);
    return View("Kq", kq);
}
```

Comment: DataSource(ds => ds.Read("Read_Intervals", "MyController") -- are you modifying Read_intervals?

Comment: no Read_Intervals just populates the DropDownList. my problem is that View cannot be opened (Rerendered) from Kq_Read controller action method.

Comment: Please post the entire View. There is no form and submit button in the View you've posted here, so it's not easy to tell where the issue is.

Comment: didn't you see the script function datesChange()! that is the jQuery function which post the selected item from DropDownList to controller action method. by calling that action method I want the entire View be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do *do something* with the returned data. When you submit an AJAX request, you need to implement a callback method that will take the returned data and update your UI with it or whatever. That's all on you, the page doesn't just automatically re-render for you.

```
$.post("@Url.Action("Kq_Read", "MyController")" + "?date=" + value, function (result) {
    // do something with `result`
});
```

Comment: I want that after calling the controller action method the entire view be rendered again. I donno how to do it using your approach!

Comment: Then just use a regular form post. The whole point of AJAX is to avoid page refreshes.